# Get associated user of DatabaseNotification

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm using DatabaseNotification with columns : type, notifiable_type and notifiable_id.
I'd like to get all notification with that type and notifiable_type and I know how to do with where clause.

```
$notificationList = DatabaseNotification::where('type','App\Notifications\NewBulletinNotification')
            ->get();
```

I know that all notifications that I want, have notifiable_id that it's a user ID.

How can I get user data with each notification?

I don't know how to add relationship function to DatabaseNotification.
expected query example:

```
$notificationList = DatabaseNotification::where('type','App\Notifications\NewBulletinNotification')
            ->with('users') // or something else with user data for each notification.
            ->get();
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `notifiable()` relation of `DatabaseNotification` Model.

```
$notificationList = DatabaseNotification::where('type','App\Notifications\NewBulletinNotification')
            ->with('notifiable')
            ->get();
```

API ref: https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Notifications/DatabaseNotification.html#method_notifiable